# How to handle two different times if they are not in the same day?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm handling restaurant opening and closing hours , i am using moment to parse time it and it works perfect but there is one case in which its not working, 
If the restaurant open at 9:00 am and closes 1:00 am (next day), it gives restaurant is closed no matter the time .

```
   if (current_time.isBetween(opening_hour, close_hour))  {
     console.log('its open');
   } else {
     console.log('its closed');
   }
```

Comment: So in this case, you have to use date along with the time.

Comment: Or save open_hour and work duration (e.g. for your case - `open_hour ` = 9:00am and `duration`=16 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic solution without mention of date, you can also test first if close_hour is before opening_hour, and if the case, use `isAfter(opening_hour) || isBefore(opening_hour)`:

NOTE: if `close_hour` is not a momentJs, the first line would be `if (moment(close_hour, 'hh:mm').isAfter(opening_hour)) {`

```
if (close_hour.isAfter(opening_hour)) {
    if (current_time.isBetween(opening_hour, close_hour)) {
        console.log('its open');
    } else {
        console.log('its closed');
    }
} else {
    if (current_time.isAfter(opening_hour) || current_time.isBefore(close_hour)) {
        console.log('its open');
    } else {
        console.log('its closed');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , I think thats it !

Answer (score 2):

What I do for such problems is actually say that the restaurant is open twice. Once from 00:00 to 01:00 and once from 09:00 to 00:00. This way, if the time validates either of those intervals, the restaurant must be open.

This approach is very similar to how you would handle, for example, lunch breaks where a store or restaurant is closed between 12:00 and 14:00 in the afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date along with the time.
Or you can also convert the date and time to epoch and then try comparing

For Eg-

```
let d1= new Date('1-1-2019').getTime(); //1546281000000
let d2= new Date('1-2-2019').getTime(); //1546367400000

let current_time= new Date().getTime(); // gives current epoch
```

Now you can write a function to check if the current_time is between d1 and d2.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to save opening hour and duration of work:

```
const opening_hour = moment('9:00am', 'hh:mm');
const current_time = moment();

const duration = 16 * 60; //duration in minutes, 16 hours

if (current_time.isBetween(opening_hour, opening_hour.clone().add(duration, 'minutes'))) {
     console.log('its open');
} else {
     console.log('its closed');
}
```

Comment: i think this would work with this one restaurant , what about the other ones who have different work durations ?

Comment: @AmrAboElenin this is just an example. If you could change the format of data for restaurants from `opening_hour` and `close_hour` to `opening_hour` and `duration` then my approach will help you. You could just get information about duration from the server. If you couldn't change the format of data, look at the solution from @RubenHelsloot

Answer (score -2):

You should change the open/close strings to moment object as well.

```
var opening_time = moment("10:40", 'hh:mm')
var closing_time = moment("23:00", 'hh:mm:ss')

if (moment().isBetween(opening_time, closing_time)) {
  console.log("Open");
} else {
  console.log("Close")
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w7e028fg/